# Google Application Update - Regarding Immediate Update for the Android Live Application

Tags: android, in-app-update, app-update, google-play-core

I am following below link to provide app update experience or feature in my android live application.

The link is here : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#java

From the link content, I am implementing Immediate App Update feature.

So far, I have done as below steps :

1. Downgraded my application version and version code as well.
2. Generated new Release APK and Insalled it in my Android device.
3. Added below code for the App update functionality in my Splash Activity.

Implemented below Code :

First added dependency : `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.1'`

Then, In Splash Activity,

```
        // Creates instance of the manager.
        final AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(SplashActivity.this);

        // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                        // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                    // Request the update.
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, SplashActivity.this,500);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else
                {
                  //Continuing with the Application flow
                }
             }
```

**The Issue is:** When I have generated Signed APK and installed in My android device.

Getting below error in log :

```
 Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:9494777414>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/emeraldsea.mobileapps.doritos.cookie
```

What might be the Issue ?

Comment: You need to provide crash stacktrace ..

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: @ADM Providing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the Solution :

While testing the App update functionality :

1. Your installed app version and version code must be lesser than that of the one which is live on Play Store.
2. Test it in Real Android Device instead of AVD or Emulator.
3. The Code in asked question is correct, **But must handle the callback in onActivityResult method.**

From Google,

With internal app sharing, you can quickly share an app bundle or APK with your internal team and testers by uploading the app bundle you want to test to the Play Console.

You can also use internal app sharing to test in-app updates, as follows:

On your test device, make sure you've already installed a version of your app that meets the following requirements:

The app was installed using an internal app sharing URL
Supports in-app updates
Uses a version code that's lower than the updated version of your app
Follow the Play Console instructions on how to share your app internally. Make sure you upload a version of your app that uses a version code that's higher than the one you have already installed on the test device.
On the test device, only click the internal app-sharing link for the updated version of your app. Do not install the app from the Google Play Store page you see after clicking the link.

Open the app from the device's app drawer or home screen. The update should now be available to your app, and you can test your implementation of in-app updates.

That's ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed one thing .it was to resume the state to check  the progress when your becomes to the foreground:
// Checks that the update is not stalled during on Resume.
// However, you should execute this check at all entry points into the app.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  appUpdateManager

      .getAppUpdateInfo()
      .addOnSuccessListener(
          appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
          });
}
```

[see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java)

Do not miss to unregister the callback if the user have the updated version and in onDestroy() method in your mainactivity

you can add this chek under onSuccess() method:

```
              } else if(appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                  appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
}
```